# Error in strtotime() conversion in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time, php-5.3, strtotime

My variable `$createdDate` has a value `'2014-06-23T01:44:22Z'` something like this in it. It's fetched from database.

And when I convert it into standard format using strtotime(), the time returned is always 2 hours different(ahead) from the orginal variable's time.

```
$time1 = strtotime($createdDate);
$cretime_formated=date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$time1);
```

Output of `$cretime_formated` is `2014-06-23 03:44:22` instead of `2014-06-23 01:44:22`. Why is there a difference of 2 hours in the time??? Is there anything wrong with my conversion process??

Comment: `strtotime()` only accepts a timestamp.

Comment: $createdDate is a timestamp. @Y U NO WORK

Comment: $createdDate is no timestamp, a timestamp is a number. But Y U NO WORK is wrong, strtotime only outputs a timestamp, it takes strings as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the date is in Zulu timezone (and assuming all such timestamps are in that same timezone), you would need [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/gmdate) to format it:

```
$cretime_formated = gmdate("Y-m-d h:i:s",$time1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the time difference .You need to set it in `UTC`

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

[See Complete Refrence](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

[List of Supported Timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)